# Software design: Shopping Cart with custom products

Tags: database-design, architecture, shopping-cart, software-design

I am building an e-commerce site and currently, I need to design the shopping cart. My requirements include having products (such as a Hamburger) that might or might not have options (different kinds of bread, extra cheese...).
What would be the best way to store the products in the shopping cart?
Storing as an array feels very flexible but will make more difficult things like counting the amount of products of each type or clasifying in default/custom (2 burgers, 1 burger with extra cheese):

```
ProductList: [
  {
    name: "Hamburger",
    extras: ""
  },
  {
    name: "Hamburger",
    extras: ""
  },
  {
    name: "Hamburger",
    extras: "Cheese"
  },
]
```

Another option would be to store them as objects with the quantity associated (I have seen this on different shopping cart implementations):

```
ProductList: [
  {
    name: "Hamburger",
    extras: "",
    quantity: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Hamburger",
    extras: "Cheese",
    quantity: 1
  },
]
```

I don't know if there is a standard approach that I don't know or depends on the domain itself.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two broad approaches here.

One is to have "[variant products](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products/product-variant)". This is common in e-commerce solutions where an item comes in different sizes, colours, etc. This approach is suitable if you know in advance what the options are (e.g. no customization of the options), and is often associated with stock keeping units - a clothes store keeps track of how many S/M/L versions of a t-shirt they have in stock.
It's not a good fit if you can have effectively infinite numbers of options, or if the options can be customized.

In your model, that would be

```
ProductList: [
  {
    name: "Hamburger",
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Hamburger with cheese",
    quantity: 1
  },
]
```

The other model is the "[Bill of materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_materials)" approach, where you group items together to specify each item in the order. This is suitable if there is no pre-defined set of options, or if the options can all be customized - e.g. "A burger with cheese, but not too much cheese".

In your model,

```
ProductList: [
  {
    name: "Hamburger",
    base_product: "Hamburger",
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Hamburger with cheese",
    base_product: "Hamburger",
    extras: 
          {
           name: "Cheese",
           amount: "A little"
           },
    quantity: 1
  },
]
```

Product variants are relatively easy to work with, but do require you to set up all the options in advance. McDonalds would be a good fit for the "product variant" option - you can have small/medium/large, single/double, etc. There are only a limited number of "meal" options.

On the other hand, an a la carte restaurant, allowing infinite menu combinations, as well as special requests, would be better using a Bill of Materials approach.